# Transpile Foundation 6 JS Plugins (Webpack) with Gulp

Tags: webpack, gulp, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

ZURB Foundation provides a couple of JS Plugins like Abide, Equalizer, Toggler, Sticky and so on...

When I'm creating a website I might not need all of them. According to my web research Foundation 6 provides single plugin js files located in foundation-sites/dist/js/plugins. The newer version of Foundation uses a Webpack syntax which I'm not really familiar with.

**Question:**
How can I transpile a set of chosen Foundation JS plugins to "normal" JavaScript/jQuery by using GULP.

Comment: So your problem is that your own code gets transpiled already, but the imported plugins use ES6 and that doesn't get transpiled?

Answer (score 0):

You can istall one of the templates and take a look at their custom config.

https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template/tree/master/src/assets/js

https://github.com/zurb/foundation-zurb-template/blob/master/src/assets/js/lib/foundation-explicit-pieces.js

A small example with just the Abide plugin would look similar to this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import { Foundation } from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.core';
import { rtl, GetYoDigits, transitionend } from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.core';
import { Box } from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.box'
import { onImagesLoaded } from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.imageLoader';
import { Keyboard } from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.keyboard';
import { MediaQuery } from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.mediaQuery';
import { Motion, Move } from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.motion';
import { Nest } from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.nest';
import { Timer } from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.timer';
import { Touch } from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.touch';
import { Triggers } from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.triggers';
import { Abide } from 'foundation-sites/js/foundation.abide';


Foundation.addToJquery($);

// Add Foundation Utils to Foundation global namespace for backwards
// compatibility.

Foundation.rtl = rtl;
Foundation.GetYoDigits = GetYoDigits;
Foundation.transitionend = transitionend;

Foundation.Box = Box;
Foundation.onImagesLoaded = onImagesLoaded;
Foundation.Keyboard = Keyboard;
Foundation.MediaQuery = MediaQuery;
Foundation.Motion = Motion;
Foundation.Move = Move;
Foundation.Nest = Nest;
Foundation.Timer = Timer;

// Touch and Triggers previously were almost purely sede effect driven,
// so no // need to add it to Foundation, just init them.

Touch.init($);

Triggers.init($, Foundation);

Foundation.plugin(Abide, 'Abide');

module.exports = Foundation;
```